# Is it possible to inherit insert options from multiple base templates?

Tags: templates, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit insert options from two templates. I created a template item and set both of the templates as base templates in the Data section. However, only the first base templates insert options are available.

Comment: Stop using Insert Options. Start using Insert Option Rules https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-insert-options-rules

Comment: Would it be possible to set an insert rule that allows all children templates of a folder?

Comment: Everything is possible with rules engine. If an action or condition is not there, you can write custom one in 10 minutes.